# using Return to push variables out of a function without printing the value

Tags: python, function, return

I was just wondering if there was a way to pass variables between functions (I use return because that is what I was taught) but not print it to the screen.

When I use

```
return userText
```

it also get printed. Is there a way round this, can I mute the print?

Comment: Return values aren't printed by default... you should post a small sample script that demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing gets printed when you use `return`.

Most likely, you're doing one of two things.

---

You may be calling the function inside a `print` call. For example:

```
def spam():
    return 'spam'

print(spam())
```

Obviously here, it's the `print` that's doing the printing, not the return. Nothing will be printed if you just do this in your script:

```
spam()
```

… or this:

```
breakfast = spam()
```

---

Or you may be using the interactive interpreter. At the prompt, if you type an expression, Python will show you the value of the expression:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> def spam():
...     return 'spam'
>>> spam()
'spam'
```

Again, that's not being caused by the `return`; it's just what the prompt does.

Often, you don't want to see the value. For example, if you do this (don't actually do this):

```
>>> def spam():
...     return 'spam\n' * 100000
>>> spam() # again, don't do this!
```

… it will spam your console with 100000 lines out output.

To avoid that, just assign the value to a variable. That way, Python doesn't have to show you the value, because you have it for later, when you need it:

```
>>> breakfast = spam()
>>> len(breakfast)
500000
```

(Actually, Python is not magically figuring out that it's safe to not print out the variable because you've stored it. In fact, it's just that you've now written a *statement* rather than an *expression*, and statements don't have values, so there's nothing for it to print out.)